# ¿Por qué algunos módulos de Python no se pueden importar localmente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Por ejemplo, **hashlib**

> (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib/20081119)

se puede descargar desde **PyPI**, descomprimirlo e importarlo con:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/hashlib-20081119")
import hashlib
```

a pesar de no estar instalado mediante *pip.*

Pero otros como **pyglet**, *pygame*, etc no tienen el archivo python para importarlo lo que te *da un error* que dice que ese módulo no existe.

¿Existe alguna manera de importarlos localmente sin tener que recurrir a la instalación de esos paquetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justamente hashlib es un mal ejemplo para lo que planteas, lo que puedes descargar es el paquete con los fuentes, que en el directorio `root` tiene un archivo `hashlib.py`, por eso cuando haces:

```
import hashlib
```

No te dá ningún error, pero si pruebas acceder a la funcionalidad en sí verás que no puedes, por que la funcionalidad, son módulos escritos en **C**, que deben ser compilados previamente, siempre que cuentes con un compilador **C**. esto lo puedes verificar viendo la carpeta `Modules`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para instalar `hashlib` si o si tienes que pasar por el el instalador que se encuentra en la pagina que adjuntaste, o el `python setup.py install` siempre que cuentes en esta caso con un compilador **C**, ni siquieras tienes disponible una distribución `.wheel` el estandar que se usa actualmente y que permite hacer un `pip install <package>`. Eventualmente podrías llegar a correr un paquete python descargado desde los fuentes si todos estos fueran código python.

Resumiendo hay varias variantes de distribución de paquetes, eso depende del desarrollador, la tecnología, la versión de python, etc. Algunas de las variantes (seguramente hay más):

- Distribución binaria tipo wheel -> comando `pip install`
- Distribución de código fuentes -> luego se ejecuta `python setup.py build`
- Setups específicos
- Codigo fuente directamente importable

Answer (score 1):

En particular, el módulo hashlib viene con `Python 2` y `Python 3`.
No hay necesidad de instalar ningún paquete, simplemente importándolo funciona.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>>
```

Otros paquetes para utilizarlos sin un virtualenv tienen que instalarse con `pip` y con `sudo`. Por ejemplo:

```
sudo pip install django
```

Otros modulos podés bajarlos de github y dentro del proyecto por lo general tiene un archivo de setup que permite la configuración del paquete. Por ejemplo:

```
python setup.py install --user
```